# Passing view field through link in twig file

Tags: php, drupal, twig, drupal-8

I am having a view1 twig template. I want to pass the field [field_program_id] in the URL field so it will be reaching contextual filter of view2. My link field on view 1 is:

```
<a class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-info btn" type="button" value="LEARN MORE" href=/program-search/details/{{ field_program_id }}>LEARN MORE</a>
```

'program-search/details' is the path of view 2. So when I select program ID = 155, I want the learn more button to create the URL as /program-search/details/155 . But currently the 155 is not getting passed correctly. Any help?!

**Screenshot of my page: https://i.stack.imgur.com/m3la3.jpg**

When I click on the 'Learn more' button I want to pass the Program ID through 'href'

Comment: where do you render/pass to the view? lets see that

Comment: Do you want to see the entire twig file or the front end? can attach a screenshot in a sec

Comment: no i want to see the php code that passes field_program_id to twig

Answer (score 0):

What if you use [string interpolation](https://twig.symfony.com/doc/3.x/templates.html#string-interpolation) and build the whole url at once?

```
<a class="button js-form-submit form-submit btn-info btn" type="button" value="LEARN MORE" href={{ "/program-search/details/#{field_program_id}" }}>LEARN MORE</a>
```

Comment: There is a quotation at the end. it's confusing. can you pls fix this?